# suggested ways of handling font-face and minification

Tags: css3

I have a css file with a font-face section in it.  Are there any known issues around using minification tools from google/yahoo when applying them on a css file with a font-face section.  If so, what are some of the workarounds that could be explored.  Not minifying is an option though I would prefer to minify the non font-face section, even if it means creating two separate files, one with non font-face css and one with font-face.  However, I am wondering if anyone has a suggested way of dealing with this without resorting to two separate HTTP requests for the CSS files.  Thanks in advance for your input/suggestions.

Comment: Voting to close. You're asking for solutions to a problem [you don't even have yet](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). Try it first and see if there even *is* a problem.

Comment: wondeitring - have you tested this on different browsers and browser versions?  I have seen multiple reports online which mentioned issues and hence wanted to inquire about best practices.  thank you in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the font face declaration from this page http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot?') format('eot'), url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'), url('GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

And ran it through yui-compressor

```
@font-face{font-family:'Graublau Web';src:url('GraublauWeb.eot?') format('eot'),url('GraublauWeb.woff') format('woff'),url('GraublauWeb.ttf') format('truetype')}
```

It appears that the minimized css will work just fine in this case.

Edit: It doesn't appear that you should be worried about base64 encoded data in font face src urls either.  I ran the css from this example page http://robert.accettura.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/embedded-font-face.html through yui-compressor, pasted it back into the file and opened it in my browser without any problems.

Comment: thank you for sharing - Mine has some base64 information in it as well.  I will revert with test results on latest browser versions.  thanks

Comment: I also tested a base64 example and updated the answer.

Comment: thank you for sharing - +1.  I will accept as soon as I test on all browsers I can test on.